# Div not staying visible on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I'll try and be as clear as possible. Please keep in mind that i am a JQuery newbie!

I'm using this code to create 1 JQuery Megamenu using a div.

I would like the menu to be triggered on hover and then fade in using `.dropdowntrigger`. I would then like the menu to fade out on mouse out of `#menuwrap`.

The issue is there needs to be a delay after it fades in as it keeps fading out before you can hover over the menu to keep it visible... I guess!

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.dropdowntrigger').hover(function() { 
    $('#menuwrap').fadeIn(500);
  }, function() { 
    $('#menuwrap').fadeOut(500); 
  });
});
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated and feel free to let me know if you require more details.

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: increase the fadeOut time? (in milliseconds)

Comment: Post a simplified version of your html please, if #menuwrap is not inside of dropdowntrigger, then what you described will occur

Comment: your fadeOut function should be bound to a `.mouseleave` function

Comment: `$('#menuwrap').on('mouseout', function(){ $('#menuwrap').fadeOut(500); })`

Comment: Without more html and css, i can we know it is not some other css interfering?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this... I have swap your fadeIn(500) and fadeout(500)

See this **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/49ypS/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdowntrigger').hover(function() { 
    $('#menuwrap').fadeOut(500);
}, function() { 
$('#menuwrap').fadeIn(500); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am thinking right so try this:

```
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseover(function() {
$('#menuwrap').fadeIn(500);
});
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseleave(function() {
$('#menuwrap').fadeout(500);
});
$('#menuwrap').mouseover(function() {
$('#menuwrap').fadeIn();
});
$('#menuwrap').mouseleave(function() {
$('#menuwrap').fadeout();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are joining the functions as a responce function, and just when the first function would finish the second would go on.

```
$(function() {
  $('.dropdowntrigger').hover(function() { 
    $('#menuwrap').fadeIn(500);
  }, function() { 
    $('#menuwrap').fadeOut(500); 
  });
});
```

This will execute when the first (`fadeIn()`) function will finish. So you need to set two seperate functions here.

Try changing them

```
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseover(function() {
  $('#menuwrap').fadeIn(500);
});
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#menuwrap').fadeout(500);
});
```

This way, the element will fadeOut only when you mouseleave the element!

You can use the setTimeOut function as:

```
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseleave(function () {
  setTimeOut(fadeOutElement, 10000);
}
```

And now, the function as:

```
function fadeOutElement() {
  $('#menuwrap').fadeOut(); 
}
```

Note that, setTimeOut is a function, which takes two arguments.

1. The function's name which is to be executed!
2. The time in milliseconds!

`setTimeOut(fadeOutElement, 10000)` will look for the function with the name `fadeOutElement` and will execute after 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds are 10 seconds).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I guess what i'm trying to achieve is a delay before fadeOut and #menuwrap needs to stay visible when being hovered over.

Comment: When you use the code I provided (the second) one the element will stay visible when is hovered over! and what type of delay? You can use `setTimeOut()` then, and in this function add the time which you need to be waited for..

Comment: Hey Afzaal, i have tried this code but still no luck. please could you let me know where i'm going wrong. $(function() {
  $('.dropdowntrigger').mouseover(function() {
  $('#menuwrap').fadeIn(500);
});
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#menuwrap').setTimeOut(1000).fadeout(500);
});
});

Comment: The #menuwrap is not fading out and is left visible.

Comment: i need it to now fade out on mouse leave.

Comment: You can see the answer now  @user2965596 :)

Comment: Thats giving me syntax error. Is there a typo on this line - function fadeOutElement. I'm new to jquery so can't figure it out right now. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: This is what i have now - 
  
  $(function() {
  $('.dropdowntrigger').mouseover(function() {
  $('#menuwrap').fadeIn(500);
});
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#menuwrap').fadeout(500);
});
$('.dropdowntrigger').mouseleave(function () {
  setTimeOut(fadeOutElement, 10000);
}
function fadeOutElement() {
  $('#menuwrap').fadeOut(); 
}
});